# Is there a name for the set $E(x, n)=\{x^p \mid p\in \mathbb N \land \space 0\leq p \leq n-1\}$ with $x\in G $, $G$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question

Source : Reversat & Bigonnet , *Algèbre pour la licence* ( = Undergraduate abstract algebra).

- The authors of the above mentionned  book define the order of element $x\in G$ as the cardinal of  $\langle x\rangle$ (i.e. $\langle \{x\}\rangle $)  , that is, the cardinal of the subgroup generated by the set $\{x\} \subseteq G$ .

Note: So $\langle x\rangle$  is  (by definition)  the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $\{x\}$.

In symbols: $$ O(x)= Card (\langle x\rangle).$$

- Then they proceed to show that this definition of $O(x)$ is equivalent to the ( maybe more common) one:

$$ O(x)= n  \iff ( x^n = e \land n= \min \{p\in \mathbb N^{*} \mid x^p = e\}) $$

with $e$ as the identity element of $G$.

- In order to prove this equivalence, they first define the set $E(x, m)$ as follows:

$$ E(x, n)=\{x^p \space \mid p\in \mathbb N \land \space 0\leq p \leq n-1\}.$$

Example: $E(x,4)= \{x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3 \}$ .

> What I'd like to know is whether there is a common name for $E(x, n)$, and whether there is a symbol communly used to denote this set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common name for $E(x,n)$, considered as a group, is $C_n$, the *cyclic group* of order $n$. So
$$
C_n=\{e,x, x^2,\ldots ,x^{n-1}\},
$$
where $x^n=x^0=e$.

In the context of your question, $C_n\cong \langle x\rangle$, where $x$ has order $n$, e.g., $x^n=e$, but $x^m\neq e$ for $1\le m<n$.

It is also common to write this by the presentation
$$
C_n=\langle x\mid x^n=e\rangle.
$$
The "C" stands for "cyclic". Another example of a group presentation is, for the dihedral group $D_n$,
$$
D_n=\{r,s\mid r^n=s^2=e, srs=r^{-1}\rangle,
$$
for $n\ge 3$. This is not a cyclic group in general.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) whether in the setting of the question $E(x,n)$ is only defined under the assumption that $n=ord(x)$. *If* that is so, you are right up to isomorphism, and also, we just have $E(x,n)= \langle x\rangle$. On the other hand, if the set is defined in greater generality, then it's just a certain subset of $G$, without a special name I am aware of.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, I agree, it is possible that $E(x,n)$ is just a subset. However, in any case the notation $C_n$ is  the important notation in this context (or the notation $\langle x \rangle$).  For such a subset of $G$ we don't need a special notation, I guess. So $E(x,n)$ is fine.